# can we program classic ASP in VSTS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, iis-7

If I have .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 + IIS 7.0 on my machine, could I develop and debug some classic ASP code (in VB Script).

If I can, any reference guide to setup development environment for both IIS 7.0 and VSTS 2008?

Answer (score 1):

[I found this article/list of tips about ASP in IIS7](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx), for developing ASP in VS2008, you don't need to do anything special, though I'd recommend first creating the site in IIS, then using File/Open site instead of using a regular project.

Comment: I read it and a little bit confused. Could we run classic ASP under .Net 3.5 worker process pool? Or I have to use .Net 1.1 worker process pool?

Comment: Doubt it matters, though in production you might want to run your ASP application in a separate pool to increase overall stability if there's a memory leak or whatever. (Eg. so that only the ASP app. goes down when something fails.)

Comment: Thanks, my question is whether classic ASP must run on .Net 1.1 or could be run on later .Net version, like .Net 3.5?

Comment: Classic ASP doesn't run on .net at all, it runs on IIS, therefor the .net version doesn't matter.

Comment: I am interested. Do you have any formal documents to prove that classic ASP does not need .Net runtime? I am confused.

Comment: Yes. Here is the ASP FAQ dated 1997: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972347.aspx.
.net 1.0 was released in 2002, five years later...